# How do I convert a text to css hex value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, hex

I need to convert a bunch of text strings into something that I can put in the "content" property. Currently I'm doing it one character at a time via this tool:

http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html

And since I'm talking about a paragraph of text and with multiple languages, it gets very tedious.

Does anyone know of any converter that translates text into the CSS Value (Hex) like in the tool above? Or at least to convert it to the JS Value (Hex).

Or at least give me a clue how to write my own tool to do such a thing (either in javascript or in php... but javascript would be much better)

Here's a sample output from the tool:

金

\91d1 (css hex value)

\u91d1 (javascript hex value)

At least let me know how it converted that character to \91d1 or \u91d1

Comment: See [*String.prototype.charCodeAt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.5).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ensures every character is converted into its Unicode value:

```
"金".charCodeAt(0).toString(16);  //91D1
```

or simply

```
escape("金");  //%u91D1
```

`escape`/`encodeURI` converts the String into its UTF-8 values except [these characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description).